# How to group many nodes? in pstricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I have this code, and would like to know how to group many nodes.

[image]

How to do it?

I prefer grouping nodes calling nodes by name but... if it´s not possible, I was thinking about coding any similar to

```
\pstriangle[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,linewidth=0.1cm,framearc=0.2](0,-1.9)(4.8,4.8)
```

with the option "linearc=0.2"

My code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-blur}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\definecolor{azultenue}{RGB}{65,170,193}
\definecolor{rojotenue}{RGB}{192,2,3}
\definecolor{naranjatenue}{RGB}{241,101,35}

\begin{document}
\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm,nodesep=0.12cm}
%
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 1cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip 1cm}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2.2, colsep=5.8]% defines the distance between two frames
 [name=Inicio] 
 \psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(0,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
%
 \rput(-1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c1}{\textcolor{black}{$c_1$}}}
 \rput(-0.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c2}{\textcolor{black}{$c_2$}}}
%
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.1,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.4,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.7,-1)
%
 \rput(1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{cl}{\textcolor{black}{$c_\lambda$}}}
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{c1}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$}}
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{c2}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$} }
%
 \ncline[arcangle=0]{->}{p1}{cl}
 \nbput[nrot=:U,labelsep=0.075cm]{\small{$ \omega_{mut}$} }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
&[name=Conjunto]
\psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(0,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
%
 \rput(-1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c1}{\textcolor{black}{$c_1$}}}
 \rput(-0.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{c2}{\textcolor{black}{$c_2$}}}
%
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.1,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.4,-1)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.06](0.7,-1)
%
 \rput(1.5,-1){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=naranjatenue]{cl}{\textcolor{black}{$c_\lambda$}}}
 \ncarcbox[nodesep=.2cm,boxsize=.4,linearc=.4,linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{<->}{p1}{c1}{c2}{cl}
\rput(0,-1.8){Evalución de Aptitud}
\rput(0,-2.25){de padres e hijos}

 \end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
\pspolygon[linearc=0.2,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue]%
  ([offset=10mm,nodesep=-4mm]p1)([offset=-5mm,nodesep=-13mm]c1)([offset=-5mm,nodesep=8mm]cl)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have coded \pstriangle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gris135,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,linewidth=0.06cm,linearc=0.4](0,-1.56)(5.0,4.2)   and I like it, but.. Are there any option to grouping ... refering to many nodes?

Comment: With `\pspolygon` you can use as may nodes as you like and `fillstyle` also works.